# Way to trigger Bootstrap's Collapse without using Buttons or A tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

A need to trigger Bootstrap's Collapse when a user clicks a Radio button, eg:

```
<input type="radio" name="radios" value="More" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample">

<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
</div>
```

But the above doesn't work.

I could wrap it in an `a` tag but that would play havoc with my styles.

Would anyone know if it's possible to trigger the collapse on click of any element?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.collapse('show');` :

```
$('#trigger').click(function(){
    $('#collapseTwo').collapse('show');
});
```

See [**JsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/kgoo9to2/)

Comment: I'm guessing there's no way to hijack Bootstrap's JS?

Comment: @MeltingDog Also i guess that, but i think we can do some tricks instead of hijacking bootstrap's JS, or at the moment we can move around solution until we have to modify bootstrap's JS or hijack it, _Thanks_